# Extract POST parameters from C String

Tags: c, post, strtok, scanf

I have the following C String:

```
char teste[] = "POST /index.html HTTP/1.1\nHost: localhost:8000\nConnection: keep-alive\nContent-Length: 23\nCache-Control: max-age=0\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+x
ml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\n Origin: http://localhost:8000\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/
537.36\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\nReferer: http://localhost:8000/index.html\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\nAccept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=
0.6,en;q=0.4\n\nnome=thiago&idade=12313";
```

And i need to extract the POST parameters, which happens after the '\n\n':

**\n\nnome=thiago&idade=12313";**

The *strtok* seems to get stuck on the first '\n', so i think there's a better way of doing this. My code so far:

```
char *token = malloc(100);
char **value  = malloc(100 * sizeof(char *));
char **key  = malloc(100 * sizeof(char *));
int i;

for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   value[i] = malloc(100);
   key[i] = malloc(100);
}

/* This doesn't work */ 
token = strtok(teste, "\n\n");
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strstr()` to locate the start of the parameters:

```
char *params = strstr(teste, "\n\n");
if (params != NULL) {
    params += 2; // now points to first key
    // ...
}
```

and then use `strtok()` to separate the key-value pairs in `params`.

*Remark:* `strtok_r()` is a reentrant version of `strtok()`, and (at least on OS X),
`strtok()` is obsoleted by `strsep()`.